# How can I find the number of elements from a list of degrees in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, database, statistics, data-science, histogram

Basically, I want to extract the average number of elements from a system which have a folding degree less than 45. To do this, I extract my data from the configuration files deposited in my folders. Then, I calculate the angles (written as "angolo" in the code) but I actually do not know how to extract the number of elements from that angle. Particularly, I do not know how to isolate the number of elements which have an angle less than 45 degree.
Does anybody know a python3 function or maybe a script to find these numbers?

```
import sys,os
import numpy as np
fn='listadir.txt' # <=== lista_dir
with open(fn,'r') as f:
  lines=f.readlines()
for l in lines:
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\simone\\anaconda3\\Ex_Files_Python_Statistics_EssT\\' + l.strip('\n'))
os.system('dir /b cnf-* > listacnf.txt')
with open('listacnf.txt','r') as f:
    linescnf=f.readlines()
    Q=np.matrix([[0.0,0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0,0.0]])
    cc = 1
for ll in linescnf:
    #print('ll=', ll)
    with open(ll.strip('\n')) as ff:
        cnft=ff.readlines()
    cnf=cnft[1:]
    for lc in cnf:
        
        lv = lc.strip('\n').split()
        #print('lc =', lc)
        
        ux = float(lv[3])
        uy = float(lv[4])
        uz = float(lv[5])
        Qxx = ux*ux
        Qxy = ux*uy
        Qxz = ux*uz
        Qyx = uy*ux
        Qyy = uy*uy
        Qyz = uy*uz
        Qzx = uz*ux
        Qzy = uz*uy
        Qzz = uz*uz
        Q += np.matrix([[Qxx, Qxy, Qxz],[Qyx, Qyy, Qyz],[Qzx,Qzy, Qzz]])
        cc += 1
        angolo = np.arccos(ux*uy*uz)
        #print(ux)
    #....
Q = Q/cc

# ....
os.chdir('..')
#print(l.strip('\n'))
N= 1000
mediangolo = angolo.mean()
frazione = mediangolo/N
print('frazione=', mediangolo)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
import numpy as np
l = np.array([10,20,30,40,50,60])
l[ l < 45] # returns: array([10, 20, 30, 40])
```

`l < 45` will return a list that is as long as `l` and `True` where the element is less than 45 and False otherwise which you can then use to select the values from the original array.

Or is you just need the count `np.count_nonzero( l < 45)` will do the trick.

Comment: The first alternative was actually the best. The count_nonzero method just added a list of ones. Much appreciated

Comment: @Zikan Your welcome! If you are fine with the answer, you can mark it accepted!